# How to apply marquee effect on the Collapsing Toolbar title of an android app

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my android application,in which I am designing using design support library, I need to make the collapsing toolbar, title and give marquee effect as the text coming from my server can sometimes be long. This is currently giving me a dot dot dot after fitting text. I was able to use marquee in list item of `RecyclerView` but same when done on collapsing toolbar title fails for me.

Comment: Use `ScrollingTextView` from this repository: [CustomViews](https://github.com/activesince93/CustomViews)

Comment: Any other way as if I am not allowed to use any third party library

Comment: Don't use library. Review the code in `library` and create `CustomTextView.java` by your self. And save that file in your any of the `package` in your Project.